# making drop shadows on UIViews

Tags: ios, uiview, shadow

I use this code in my customized UIView initialization:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        ...

        UIBezierPath *shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.size.height, frame.size.width, 15)];
        self.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
        self.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 4.0f);
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5f;
        self.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.CGPath;
    }
    return self;
}
```

trying to make a drop shadow like this:

1)

[image]

But I got this effect:

2)

[image]

You can see this is an upside down version of what I want to achieve. How to make the shadow effect of the first image?

Comment: why you are not doing this UIBezierPath *shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:view.bounds];

Comment: This line will drop shadows on the entire view. I just want the shadow to appear at the bottom of the UIView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is just with your `shadowPath`.

Using `CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.size.height, frame.size.width, 15)` to create your `UIBezierPath` will set an incorrect origin.

First, `origin.x` should be `0.0f` or the shadow will shift far away if your `UIView`'s `origin.x != 0.0f`. Second, you need to line up the bottom of the `shadowPath` with the bottom of your `UIView`.

This is a screenshot of `UIView`s using your shadow code illustrating these issues. (In the lower `UIView` you cannot see the shadow because it is far off the right of the screen).
[image: Screenshot with incorrect shadowPath]

You will see what you intended if you change the rect to:

```
const CGFloat shadowRectHeight = 15.0f;
CGRect shadowRect = CGRectMake(0.0f, self.bounds.size.height - shadowRectHeight, self.bounds.size.width, shadowRectHeight)];
```

[image: Screenshot with correct shadowPath]

Comment: Thanks. Although the main problem is that my customized uiview is sitting at the bottom of its parent view so other views are overlapping its shadow, I think this answer is very helpful and saved me some time.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this and set the `UIView alpha`

```
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];  
gradient.frame = rect;  
gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[UIColor blackColor].CGColor,   
                                            (id)[UIColor grayColor].CGColor,   
                                            (id)[UIColor blackColor].CGColor,nil];  
[self.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
```

you can add or remove UIColor you want to display.